# Add Dynamic @return code hinting in Netbeans php

Tags: php, netbeans, code-hinting

I have a ->load() method that includes and returns given class name.
So it can return different data types.
Can I enable any kind of code hinting in netbeans?

```
$msg = $this->load('message');
$msg-> // hinting should list message class methods

$usr = $this->load('user');
$usr-> // hinting should list user class methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question has been answered here:
[Dynamic return type with type hint in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941809/dynamic-return-type-with-type-hint-in-php)

> any kind of code hinting

Yes, try this.

```
$usr = $this->load('user');/* @var $usr user */
```

You may wanna use shortcut "vdoc" and press {tab} in the code to generate the type-hinting comment.

Comment: I think I tried similar trick, BTW I'll try this again and check if it works.

Comment: Note that there is difference if you are typehinting inside method (as I did - after the variable decalration) or a class attribute (in that case - the parenthesis should be above the attribute)..

(If sth does not work, you may try  /** , /*, @var, @param...)